# Late static binding in older PHP versions

Tags: php

Consider the following scenario:

```
interface Validatable {
     static function validate($input);
}

class Field implements Validatable {
     static function validate($input) {
          return $input;
     }
}
```

Then, I call the function statically:

```
Field::validate($input);
```

But I Get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
```

I know what the error means: `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` stands for double colon in hebrew, which means thet the double colon is a syntax error. But how would I call a static function, without double colons?

**NOTE**: This works fine in PHP versions 5.4/5.3. The problem is with versions 5.2/5.1. How can the issue be fixed without updating the PHP version?

Comment: what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: http://ideone.com/Fo74Uh so clearly the issue isn't quite what you think

Comment: Have you tried putting `public` before the `static` keyword in the function declaration?

Comment: @tas9 [`static` methods are `public` by default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) `:)`

Comment: Your code works perfectly on PHP 5.x. Can give more details? What php version do you use? Sometimes 5.2.x versions give us such errors.

Comment: This is actually an issue reported by one of the users of a certain program that I am managing, and Im not sure what his PHP version. If I set NetBeans to use PHP 5.2/5.1 it does throw an error, though.

Comment: Can you post more code? Your snippet works fine for me (echo Field::validate(1); // displays 1)

Comment: http://3v4l.org/tMnCQ 5.0.0-5.6.0 alpha 1 works

Answer (score 1):

See [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php#96137) on the docs page for interfaces.  It looks like you're still on PHP <=5.2 and don't have access to [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/lsb).

A workaround would be to not make the function static:

```
<?php
interface Validatable {
     function validate();
}

class Field implements Validatable {
    protected $input;

    function __construct($input) {
        $this->input = $input;
    }
     function validate() {
          return $this->input;
     }
}

$field = new Field('input');

var_dump($field->validate());
```

**Edit**

If you must have a static method, a general workaround is to use an inner method that calls to your static method using the keyword `self`:

```
<?php

interface Validatable {
     static function validate($input);
}

class Field implements Validatable {
     static function myValidate($input) {
         return self::validate($input);
     }

    static function validate($input) {
        return $input;
    }
}

print_r(Field::myValidate('test'));
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work in your case, but you can give it a try.  I was able to get this to run at http://phptester.net/

Comment: I understand that, but if updating the PHP version is not an option, how can I fix the issue?

Comment: The only way is to change the type-hinting on the function signature that is being called to a concrete type (I know, not much of a solution). A better solution would be to change your minimum requirements.

Comment: Can you think of another way to design this code snippet to "fake" late static binding for PHP < 5.3?

Comment: I can't see what this has to do with `late static binding`: it's calling a `static` method... not the same thing at all

Comment: @watcher I need a workaround while still keeping that method static.

Comment: @Mark Baker last I checked, calling static methods were allowed in PHP 5.2... what change occurred in PHP 5.3 that would allow static methods in interfaces if not LSB? (Not saying static methods in interfaces is a good idea by any means, I believe its pretty much equivalent to abstract static methods, but that's not the point)

Comment: Except the code as posted works in all releases of PHP 5.x, and doesn't use late static binding in any way (there isn't any inheritance even to use LSB. The posted code is a simple static method in a class. Until Yoav posts a real example to show his problem code, it's difficult to help him.... The interface doesn't contain a static method, it merely contains information that any classes that implement that interface must contain a static method with that name and accepting that argument